# print coupon with image and content written on it in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

In my jsp i have print button , on that button i want to display data which is already available in js.

```
  jQuery("#printCoupon").click(function() {
        PrintDiv();
    });

    function PrintDiv() {    

        var divToPrint = couponCode;
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=800');

        var htmlCode='<table frame="box" style="border-style: dashed;" ><div align="left" class="printDiv" style="vertical-align:middle;height: 6px;width: 9px;max-width:350px;margin:10% auto 0;" ><tr><td>';
        popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()"><div style="text-align:center;">Coupon Details</div>'+htmlCode+'' +buisnessName+''+dealTitle+'<br/>'+dealDesc+'<br/>'+dealendDate+'<br/>'+ couponCode + '</div></table></html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
        popupWin.window.close();
             }
```

this data is displaying well but now i want to have coupon as image and then all this content to be added in it.

> I tried using
>
> ```
>  background-image: url("../images/automotive_section_bg.png");
>     background-repeat: repeat;
> ```
>
> But it is not at all working I also tried written css in separate file
>   but the css is not applying to this as it is opening new window.

Here is the jsFiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/pw111ktm/
```

Please help.

Comment: Can u create a jsfiddle for your requirement

Comment: @Manikanta Reddy Please see the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/pw111ktm/

Comment: try using ----------@media print----------- in your css

Comment: @ManikantaReddy where should i add it? as giving css from outside not working here.